# Django ValueError: Cannot assign must be an instance

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

when i try to insert data to my database through manage.py shell, i got this error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Ciawigebang'": "Desa.kecamatan" must be a "Kecamatan" instance.
```

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Kecamatan(models.Model):
    kecamatan = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.kecamatan

class Desa(models.Model):
    desa = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    kecamatan = models.ForeignKey(Kecamatan, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.desa
```

here my json file snippet scrap.json

```
[
    {
        "Kecamatan": "Ciawigebang",
        "Desa": [
            "Ciawigebang",
            "Ciawilor",
            "Cigarukgak",
            "Cihaur",
            "Cihirup",
            "Cijagamulya",
            "Cikubangmulya",
            "Ciomas",
            "Ciputat",
            "Dukuhdalem",
            "Geresik",
            "Kadurama",
            "Kapandayan",
            "Karangkamulya",
            "Kramatmulya",
            "Lebaksiuh",
            "Mekarjaya",
            "Padarama",
            "Pajawanlor",
            "Pamijahan",
            "Pangkalan",
            "Sidaraja",
            "Sukadana",
            "Sukaraja"
        ]
    },{
        "Kecamatan": "Cibeureum",
        "Desa": [
            "Cibeureum",
            "Cimara",
            "Kawungsari",
            "Randusari",
            "Sukadana",
            "Sukarapih",
            "Sumurwiru",
            "Tarikolot"
        ]
    },{
        "Kecamatan": "Cibingbin",
        "Desa": [
            "BANTAR PANJANG",
            "CIANGIR",
            "Cibingbin",
            "Cipondok",
            "CISAAT",
            "Citenjo",
            "DUKUHBADAG",
            "Sindang Jawa",
            "SUKA MAJU",
            "SUKAHARJA"
        ]
    }...
]
```

this is the code i use to insert the data to database from python manage.py shell

```
import json
from apps.models import Desa, Kecamatan
with open('scrap.json') as f:
    daerahs = json.load(f)

for daerah in daerahs:
    for x in daerah['Desa']:
        y=Desa(desa=x, kecamatan=daerah['Kecamatan'])
        y.save()
```

how to solve this? there's so many similar question but i can't figure it out how to solve this problem in  my case. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `Kecamatan instance`. Change your code to this

```
for daerah in daerahs:
    kecamatan, created = Kecamatan.objects.get_or_create(kecamatan=daerah['Kecamatan'])
    for x in daerah['Desa']:
        y = Desa(desa=x, kecamatan=kecamatan)
        y.save()
```

follow this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to understand `get_or_create`

Comment: it works but it create many 'kecamatan' objects, what i mean is for instance in scrap.json file for 'kecamatan : cibeureum' theres 8 'desa' and in the database it creates 8 'kecamatan cibeureum'. can it create only one?

Comment: @triefauzan yes, you right. i updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `loaddata` from your terminal `python manage.py loaddata scrap.json`

the format for the loaded data should be like this:

```
[
    {
     "pk": 1,
     "model": "app.desa",
     "fields": {
     "kecamatan": 1,
     "desa": "Ciawigebang"
     },
      {
     "pk": 2,
     "model": "app.desa",
     "fields": {
     "kecamatan": 1,
     "desa": "Ciawigebang"
     }
]
```

for every instance of `Desa` you provide a unique id and for the field `kecamatan` you use it's id since its a foriegn key (you need to populate the `Kecamatan` model with values, before populating the `Desa` models.)

meaning you should initially create another json file for Kecamatan, and load with with `loaddata`

```
[
        {
         "pk": 1,
         "model": "app.kecamatan",
         "fields": {
         "kecamatan": "Ciawigebang",
         },
          {
         "pk": "Cibeureum",
         "model": "app.kecamatan",
         "fields": {
         "kecamatan": 1,
         }
 ]
```

**NOTE:** app should be the name of your app that the Desa and Kecamatan models reside.